# Xpath to get element having specific tag in nearest surrounding relative to given element

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

I have an element with `id` say `uniqueId`
There are various tags surrounding it, I want to get specific tag in it's nearest.

Here is an example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input> </input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form>
            .
                .
                <input id="uniqueId"> </input>
                .
            .
        </form>
    <div>
</div>
```

I want to get say nearest `input` tag if I have xpath of say `id="uniqueId"`.

I tried Something like
`<ancestor-siblings>::[@tag="input"]`
and 
`//*[@id="uniqueId"]/parent::following-sibling::input`

or something like  `//*/input/*/[@id="uniqueId"]`

I have to use this in Selenium.

I have gone through various Xpath cheatsheets but couldn't achieved what I require.

Comment: What does "the nearest" mean, exactly? Also, what's `<ancestor-siblings>`? On top of that, backslashes do not work in XPath. None of your attempts is even remotely syntactically valid. You have not tried *anything* yet, not for a minute.

Comment: @Tomalak: Nearest mean, it has to be nearest if we traverse the DOM from the element's xpath we have. `<ancestor-siblings>` that's I am just asking if there is any way we can do such thing. I corrected the slash thing

Comment: From the input tag with the id you need to move up atleast two levels to get to div (or better off using ancestor::form and moving up a level), then use preceding-sibling to get to the div above it and then get the input tag inside it. Also the xpath you are trying with parent::following... will give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find 1st `preceding input` for `[@id='uniqueId']` element. You can try same with `following::` instead.

```
//*[@id='uniqueId']/preceding::input[1]
```

Is that what you asked?

Comment: Exactly I was looking for.

I also came up with something like: 
`//*[@id="professional"]/ancestor::div[@data-bind="ojModule: dynamicConfig()"]`

Or


`//*[@id="professional"]/../../../../../../../../descendant::input[@type="text"]`

But your solution is on spot.